# Hide year if it is the current year

Tags: php, date

I have a function to display the date of an article:

```
get_the_date('M j, Y');
```

This will return the date in a string:

> Apr 10, 2015

I want to hide the year if it is the **current year**. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code for the_date

Comment: @dbinns66 I can't change the function, it is a WordPress core function. I can only filter through the returned date string.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date_str=get_the_date('M j, Y');
$parts= explode(",",date_str );
// some validation
if ($parts[1]==date("Y")) //then same year
{
  $date_str = $parts[0]; //just the month
}

//your string in $date_str...
```

Comment: How much different is your solution to the other one posted? Is it any different in terms of performance?

Comment: I imagine the difference is negligible, but i used your function output as reference.

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know what's there in your `get_the_date` function. This might help you.

```
if(date('Y')==get_the_date('Y')){
    get_the_date('M j');
}
else{
    get_the_date('M j, Y');
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, date('Y') gives the current year, right?